# Checking if a different region exists at the specified radius

Tags: java, bukkit

I create plots based on worldguard regions. I am looking for a good method of checking if there is no other region within a radius of 50 counts in each direction. My point is that someone does not create a plot and someone else's plot. Currently, I checked it in a strange way for me, but it practically worked.

```
    Location p3 = p.getLocation();
    p3.setX(p3.getBlockX());
    p3.setY(60);
    p3.setZ(p3.getBlockZ()+size);
    if(region.getApplicableRegions(p3).size() == 0) {
        plotsCheck.put(p.getUniqueId(), plotsCheck.get(p.getUniqueId())+1);
    }

    Location p3a = p.getLocation();
    p3a.setX(p3a.getBlockX());
    p3a.setY(60);
    p3a.setZ(p3a.getBlockZ()+10);
    if(region.getApplicableRegions(p3a).size() == 0) {
        plotsCheck.put(p.getUniqueId(), plotsCheck.get(p.getUniqueId())+1);
    }

    Location p4 = p.getLocation();
    p4.setX(p4.getBlockX());
    p4.setY(60);
    p4.setZ(p4.getBlockZ()-size);
    if(region.getApplicableRegions(p4).size() == 0) {
        plotsCheck.put(p.getUniqueId(), plotsCheck.get(p.getUniqueId())+1);
    }
```

In this way, I checked if it was empty. If so, I added 1 point to the hashmap.
Unfortunately, this does not always work and ends with the fact that several plot plots belong to 2 people. Does anyone of you propose a different solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

WorldGuard already has some built in features for that.

```
RegionContainer container = getWorldGuard().getRegionContainer();
RegionManager manager = container.get(world);

Region newRegion = //create your region somehow
manager.addRegion(newRegion);

List<ProtectedRegion> regions = new ArrayList<ProtectedRegion>(manager.getRegions().values());

List<ProtectedRegion> overlappingRegions = newRegion.getIntersectingRegions(regions);

if (overlappingRegions.size() > 0) {
    //delete region newRegion
} else {
   //region is valid 
}
```

This of course works only after the region has already been created.

Code has not been tested. Just searched through the WorldGuard API wiki.

https://worldguard.enginehub.org/en/latest/developer/regions/protected-region/#finding-intersecting-regions